# Listing all values from tuple key in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary with a tuple as key, such as the following:

```
d1 = {}
d1[(111,1)] = "value1111"
d1[(111,2)] = "value1112"
d1[(111,3)] = "value1113"
d1[(112,1)] = "value1121"
d1[(112,2)] = "value1122"
d1[(112,3)] = "value1123"
```

How can I get all the values for a given number in the first element of the tuple key? That is, for the `111`, I want to obtain the following:

```
value1111
value1112
value1113
```

I've tried `print(d1[(111,i)])` but it only returns one value, is there a simple way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use list comprehension, this way:

```
[v for k,v in d1.items() if k[0]==111]
```

The condition `if k[0]==111` means return only values of `d1` whose key's first element is `111`

You were also trying with `print(d1[(111,i)]`,that will work if you have a control over the range and types of the second element of key's tuple, i.e:

```
>>> [d1[(111,i)] for i in range(1,4)]
['value1111', 'value1112', 'value1113']
```

In your example, we know that the `i` can only be from 1 to 3, hence `range(1,4)`, but if you don't know what's the range of `i` and even what the type of `i` could be, then the list comprehension is your best friend here.

Of course, one can get the list of second element of key's tuple whose first element is `111` by doing so:

```
>>>my_filter = [k[1] for k in d1 if k[0]==111]
[2, 3, 1]
>>>my_list = [d1[(111,i) for i in my_filter]
['value1112', 'value1113', 'value1111']
```

Answer (score 7):

A simple list comprehension will do the trick:

```
>>> [d1[tup] for tup in d1 if tup[0] == 111]
['value1112', 'value1113', 'value1111']
```

It says "for every key `tup` in the dictionary, give me the corresponding value if the key's first element is 111".

Answer (score 2):

If you control how the dict is created and want to group by the first element of your tuples forget using tuples as keys and  use a `defaultdict` appending to a list to handle repeated keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d1 = defaultdict(list)
d1[111].append("value1111")
d1[111].append( "value1112")
d1[111].append("value1113")
d1[112].append("value1121")
d1[112].append("value1122")
d1[112].apendd("value1123")
```

Then you can get all the values at once or index the list to pull the ith value:

```
In [17]: d1

Out[17]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {111: ['value1111', 'value1112', 'value1113'],
             112: ['value1121', 'value1122']})
In [18]: d1[111]
Out[18]: ['value1111', 'value1112', 'value1113']

In [19]: d1[111][0]
Out[19]: 'value1111'

In [20]: d1[111][1]
Out[20]: 'value1112'
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think the default dict approach is the most flexible and allows you to query other values easily (e.g. 112 or 113).  In the code below, d2 will be a map from the 111, 112, 113 to their respective values.

```
d2 = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in d1.iteritems():
    d2[key[0]].append(value)

print d2[111]
print d2[112]
```